# SSH connects to the wrong host (IPv6)

Tags: ssh, ipv6, openwrt

#### TL;DR:

I have two hosts, `opi` and `bpi`.

When I do `ssh bpi`, I get connected to `opi`. I have traced the problem down to `ssh opi` connecting by IPv4, but `ssh bpi` using (a wrong) IPv6 address. I see my OpenWRT router thinks that is associated with `bpi`, but it actually shows up (`ip address show eth0`) instead on `opi`.

I can post `ip address show` output etc., but I'm not sure what is private and what not with IPv6. The problematic address has a scope of `global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute`.

I don't want to start turning off everything IPv6 I see on the router, but I also can't understand whats wrong.

#### Details:

I have been trying to read up on IPv6 because of this problem, but I usually stay clear of networking stuff as it is not very satisfying and has lots of difficult areas.

The behaviour triggers a SSH host-key change DNS spoofing alert, so that is good. It may have something to do with OpenWRT's IPv6, but I cannot find anyone else or open issues.  Also I have not setup anything to do IPv6. This is how it came, and the router was flashed last month with OpenWrt 21.02.1.

All of the boxes are Debian-based Linux. This problem appears on all three laptops I tried. All hosts are given static DHCP leases with DNS names using OpenWRT's dnsmasq service. The `/etc/hosts` file on each host is stock (except for a list of `*.zt` aliases for adresses provided by ZeroTier).

If I connect to the IPv4 addresses directly or the ZeroTier aliases then everything works as expected.

`opi` does not show up as IPv6 host in OpenWRT.
`bpi` does show, but with an address of `opi`.
Both boxes have distinct MAC's, I put those in dnsmasq for the static DHCP assignment and also keep them around in my config files for WOL.

I can connect all of their IPv6 addresses, except one on each. This may be some special address, I know almost nothing anymore about IPv6 except that I did a he.net tutorial years ago.

What can I try besides trying to turn off IPv6 altogether?

Should I set an IPv6 suffix in OpenWRT?

---

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` as requested, is as-is shipped by Ubuntu 10/Debian 11:

```
passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

And `/etc/hosts` as well (or at least the IPv6 part):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   t460s

# Some IPv4 aliases here, nothing more
# 10.147.*.*    *.zt

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Nameservers are `127.0.0.53` in on this laptop or `192.168.3.1` on all others including `opi`/`bpi` (192.168.3.1 is the OpenWRT gateway).

```
$ nslookup opi.lan
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   opi.lan
Address: 192.168.3.182
```

```
$ nslookup bpi.lan
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   bpi.lan
Address: 192.168.3.160
Name:   bpi.lan
Address: fd26:256d:8eef::17f
```

```
$ ssh bpi.zt nslookup bpi
Server:     192.168.3.1
Address:    192.168.3.1#53

Name:   bpi.lan
Address: 192.168.3.160
Name:   bpi.lan
Address: fd26:256d:8eef::17f
```

And on the gateway itself `uci show dhcp`:

```
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0]=dnsmasq
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].domainneeded='1'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].localise_queries='1'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].rebind_protection='1'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].rebind_localhost='1'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].local='/lan/'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].domain='lan'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].expandhosts='1'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].authoritative='1'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].readethers='1'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].leasefile='/tmp/dhcp.leases'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].resolvfile='/tmp/resolv.conf.d/resolv.conf.auto'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].localservice='1'
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].ednspacket_max='1232'
dhcp.lan=dhcp
dhcp.lan.interface='lan'
dhcp.lan.start='100'
dhcp.lan.limit='150'
dhcp.lan.leasetime='12h'
dhcp.lan.dhcpv4='server'
dhcp.lan.dhcpv6='server'
dhcp.lan.ra='server'
dhcp.lan.ra_flags='managed-config' 'other-config'
dhcp.wan=dhcp
dhcp.wan.interface='wan'
dhcp.wan.ignore='1'
dhcp.odhcpd=odhcpd
dhcp.odhcpd.maindhcp='0'
dhcp.odhcpd.leasefile='/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
dhcp.odhcpd.leasetrigger='/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'
dhcp.odhcpd.loglevel='4'

dhcp.@host[0]=host
dhcp.@host[0].name='xxx'
dhcp.@host[0].dns='1'
dhcp.@host[0].mac='x:x:x:x:x:x'
dhcp.@host[0].ip='192.168.3.x'
```

IPv6 routes:

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fd26:256d:8eef::3b5 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
fd26:256d:8eef::d1c dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fd26:256d:8eef::/64 dev enp0s31f6 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fd26:256d:8eef::/64 dev wlp3s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fd26:256d:8eef::/48 via fe80::9ade:d0ff:fe5e:534c dev enp0s31f6 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fd26:256d:8eef::/48 via fe80::9ade:d0ff:fe5e:534c dev wlp3s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ztuku7oncs proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
```

Typical `resolv.conf`:

```
search lan
nameserver 192.168.3.1
nameserver fd26:256d:8eef::1
```

---

```
$ ssh bpi
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The ECDSA host key for bpi has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address fd26:256d:8eef::17f
is unchanged. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
Offending key for IP in /home/hari/.ssh/known_hosts:113
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/hari/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "fd26:256d:8eef::17f"
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:UdjpmN7FNjdrvUWRMXPDYW6wURx0BU3N/AeuZpf0oTc.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/hari/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/hari/.ssh/known_hosts:149
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/hari/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "bpi"
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Agent forwarding is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
  ___  ____  _    ___             
 / _ \|  _ \(_)  / _ \ _ __   ___ 
| | | | |_) | | | | | | '_ \ / _ \
| |_| |  __/| | | |_| | | | |  __/
 \___/|_|   |_|  \___/|_| |_|\___|
                                  
Welcome to Armbian 21.02.2 Focal with Linux 5.10.60-sunxi
...
```

```
$ ssh bpi.zt
 ____  ____  _ 
| __ )|  _ \(_)
|  _ \| |_) | |
| |_) |  __/| |
|____/|_|   |_|
               
Welcome to Armbian 21.02.3 Focal with Linux 5.10.60-sunxi
...
```

Two things I'll look at later:

- Does any resolve.conf have any special things, like `resolve.conf.d` maybe...
- Does it matter it there is a managed switch in between, that is also new...
- Is mDNS something I can do, would that `search local` 'hide' the issue maybe

But I think I really have to dig into OpenWRT and go see if I should bug those guys.

Comment: Do opi and bpi have different Ethernet MAC addresses?

Comment: Yes, their hardware addresses are different. I almost looked at spoofing MAC but there was no need, they really are not the same.

Comment: You must provide more details: Show the addresses, the nameservers, the hosts file and the name services configuration (/etc/nsswitch.conf typically).

Comment: @U.Windl I understand. But there is not much to look at, I could not find anything interesting. Have never used `nsswitch.conf` btw.

Comment: Correct: "there's to much to look at" **for us**. So don't expect we can help you.

Comment: Well I still hope IPv6 isn't magic but I like I said, if there is anything on my end I should look at I'm all ears.

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with ssh or the client machine.  You say in your opening section that your OpenWRT has the wrong address. `/etc/nsswitch.conf` shows that an IPv6 address isn't coming through MDNS so it must either be in `/etc/hosts` incorrectly or coming through DNS (from the router).  Long story short, this looks like something has got screwed up in the router.

Comment: The other point that is curious here is that `opi` and `spi` are not [FQDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).  They are missing the top level domain.  That's likely coming from your router specifying a search domain list (you'll see `search ...` in`/etc/resolv.conf`).  It may be `opi.lan` and `bpi.lan` as you've already tried.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I forgot about `resolv.conf`, have not had to look at this in years. Yes, `search lan` is the setting as I have known it on these Debian/OpenWRT setups.

I take it I can ignore my thinkpad seems to be running a DNS as well, and should focus on what DNS or other things on OpenWRT are doing? Every other host just has `search lan`/`nameserver 192.168.3.1`/`nameserver fd26:256d:8eef::1`. I guess `lan` is something I could replace with real domain if I wanted to keep public DNS records as well for some of these hosts?

Comment: @mpe yes.  it was only important to be sure what exactly is being looked up.  As you already knew the real DNS lookup is `bpi.lan`.  This again points to the problem originating in OpenWRT since that will be the authoritative DNS server for `.lan` domains.  If you wanted to replace this you would do so on the DHCP server (router?).  You could replace `.lan` with `.local` which would mean clients use MDNS instead if DNS.  Host's manage their own MDNS response and cut out OpenWRT from the lookup.